# Semaphore-like object for jumping out of "infinite loop" needed

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, semaphore, ros

I am working on a rospy project on a Raspberry Pi 2.
The pyhton script needs to start a thread whenever a message is received and loop it until another message is received.
But since these threads need access to Hardware, every time I receive a new message the old thread should stop.
I build my own locking system, but it fails when flooded with messages.
Right now I'm looking into semaphores but either I'm not quite getting how they work or I need something else, but similar to a semaphore.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
def some_thread():
    # lock_int is 0 when noone uses the hardware, 1 when another thread uses it
    global lock_int

    # my way of signaling that I want to get the Hardware access
    lock_int += 1

    # wait until other thread releases Hardware
    while(lock_int > 1):
        wait()

    # loop until some other thread requests hardware
    while(lock_int < 2)
        do_hardware_stuff()

    # release hardware
    lock_int -= 1
```

If I wanted to do this with a semaphore I would need some kind of signal in the do_hardware_stuff loop to see the request.
Something like this:

```
def semaphore_thread():
    # blocking request, waits until other thread releases
    semaphore.acquire()

    # loop until some other thread requests hardware
    while(semaphore.got_request() != True)
        do_hardware_stuff()

    # release hardware
    semaphore.release()
```

Is there a way I can use semaphores or similar objects like this?

Thanks,
ChTe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using a Queue for the hardware jobs.
I put a lock around the Queue to avoid editing the Queue at the same time from different places.
I left my lock_int mechanism in place, but since i'm running a kill thread function before starting a new job out of the queue,
I can guarantee that there is only one job running.

```
def kill_thread():
    global lock_int

    lock_int += 1

    while(lock_int > 1):
        wait()

    lock_int -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could start more threads and use `threading.Lock` to do threads synchronization.

for example:

```
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()

def semaphore_thread():

    lock.acquire()
    try:
        do_hardware_stuff()
    finally:
        lock.release()
```

Comment: But this doesn't loop the do_harware_stuff() part.
The main problem is to get some kind of notice in the loop to jump out and release the hardware.